# Attribute Routing issue in WebAPi

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, angularjs-routing

I've my **controller** code as

```
$scope.srchbycat = function () {
    var promisePost = MyService.getbyCat($scope.txttitle,$scope.txtGenre,$scope.txtClassification,$scope.txtDate,$scope.txtRating,$scope.txtCast);
}
```

**Service:**

```
this.getbyCat = function (title, genre, classification, releaseDate, rating, cast) {
    return $http.post('/api/Movies/GetMovieByCategory',
        { Cast: cast, Classification: classification, Genre: genre, MovieId: 0, Rating: rating, ReleaseDate: releaseDate, Title: title });
    }
```

**APICOntroller:**

```
    [Route("api/Movies/GetMovieByCategory")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IEnumerable<MovieData> GetMovieByCategory([FromBody]MovieData movieData)  
    {  
        IEnumerable<MovieData> movieDataByCat = null;
        string[] paramCast;
        if(movieData.Cast.Count()!=0)
        paramCast = movieData.Cast;
        IEnumerable<MovieData> GetAllMovies = null;
        GetAllMovies = repo.GetAll();

        if (movieData.Cast == null || movieData.Cast.Count() == 0)
        {
            movieDataByCat = from data in GetAllMovies
                             where (data.Classification == (movieData.Classification == null ? string.Empty : movieData.Classification) ||
                                    data.Genre == (movieData.Genre == null ? string.Empty : movieData.Genre) ||
                                    data.Rating == movieData.Rating ||
                                    data.ReleaseDate == movieData.ReleaseDate ||
                                    data.Title == (movieData.Title == null ? string.Empty : movieData.Title))

                             select data;
        }
        return movieDataByCat;
    }
```

**Issue :**
I try to call this action, I'll be able to see values being passed in Controller as well as service but when APIController hits, `MovieData` parameters are showing as null.
And also two set of arrays are coming even though 5 parameters are passed from UI. Image FYR.
[Error image while debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7d2AZ.png)
What would be the solution.

Comment: Try removing the [FromBody]?

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't work out ! Still same problem.